# updating libpng on mac

Tags: python, system, libpng, dlib

I am trying to use a python package (dlib) on my mac OSX running 10.12.3. However, the error I am getting is:

```
ImportErrordlopen(/Users/xargon/anaconda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dlib.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libpng16.16.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/xargon/anaconda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dlib.so
Reason: Incompatible library version: dlib.so requires version 41.0.0 or later, but libpng16.16.dylib provides version 39.0.0
```

I tried to update using:

```
brew upgrade libpng
```

However, this had no effect. I also uninstalled and reinstalled dlib after that.

Can someone tell me how I can upgrade my system so that this dependency is resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a virtual environment? If yes, you need remove libpng from it completely  by using `brew uninstall libpng`. After that, you should deactivate the virtual environment and type `brew uninstall libpng`.

After this, try to make the library again from scratch. This should solve your problem.

P.S. If you have multiple libpng versions installed, you need to remove them, too!